# How to save data from the data stream while not blocking the stream? (PyQt5 signal emit() performance)

Tags: python, pyqt, python-multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I'm developing a PyQt5 application.
In my application, it has a data stream, and its speed is about 5~20 data/sec.

Every time data arrives, the following `onData()` method of class `Analyzer` is called. (Following code is simplified code of my app)

```
class Analyzer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.dataDeque = deque(MAXLENGTH=10000)
    def onData(self, data):
        self.dataDeque.append({
            "data": data, 
            "createdTime": time.time()
        })
        self.cnt += 1
        if self.cnt % 10000 == 0:
            pickle.dump(dataDeque, open(file, 'wb'))
```

But the problem is, this dataDeque object is so large(50~150MB) so that dumping the pickle takes about 1~2 seconds.

During that moment(1~2 seconds), requests for calling `onData()` method got queued, and after 1~2 seconds, the queued requests call lots of `onData()` method at simultaneously, eventually distorts the `createdTime` of data.

To solve this problem, I edited my code to use Thread (QThread) to save the pickle.

The following code is the edited code.

```
from PickleDumpingThread import PickleDumpingThread
pickleDumpingThread = PickleDumpingThread()
pickleDumpingThread.start()

class Analyzer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.dataDeque = deque(MAXLENGTH=10000)
    def onData(self, data):
        self.dataDeque.append({
            "data": data, 
            "createdTime": time.time()
        })
        self.cnt += 1
        if self.cnt % 10000 == 0:
            pickleDumpingThread.pickleDumpingSignal.emit({
                "action": savePickle,
                "deque": self.dataDeque
            })
            # pickle.dump(dataDeque, open(file, 'wb'))
```

The following code is `PickleDumpingThread` class.

```
class PickleDumpingThread(QThread):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.daemon = True
       self.pickleDumpingSignal[dict].connect(self.savePickle)

   def savePickle(self, signal_dict):
       pickle.dump(signal_dict["deque"], open(file, 'wb'))
```

I expected this newly edited code will dramatically decrease the stream blocking time(1~2 seconds), but this code still blocks the stream about 0.5~2 seconds.

It seems like `pickleDumpingThread.pickleDumpingSignal.emit(somedict)` takes 0.5~2 seconds.

My question is 3 things.

1. Is signal emit() function's performance is not good like this?
2. Is there any possible alternatives of emit() function in my case?
3. Or is there any way to save pickle while not blocking the data stream?
   (any suggestion of modifying my code is highly appreciated)

Thank you for reading this long question!

Comment: you're not using your qThread as follows, all hard task should be done under `run()` method in `PickleDumpingThread`

Comment: Similar to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329462/pyqt-qthread-multithreading-does-not-work

Comment: @PYPL Thanks for your comment. It seems like I'm using QThread and Signal in wrong way. However, I'm having trouble with modifying my code to transform my original code to done in `run()` method.

Everytime signal emitted, I need to call `pickle.dump(..., ...)`. How can I implement this with (one time called) `run()` method?

Comment: What's in `data`? You might be able to use something better than `pickle` (e.g. `json`) which will be faster, more stable, and not be a security risk when giving it untrusted data.

Comment: @TheCompiler `data` is an object of some class I made. I'm thinking of transforming my object to simple dictionary as a final solution, but I'm afraid of that transformation also taking some time. (I found that my stream data comes every 0.01 seconds, so any task in saving pickle should take less than 0.01 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work

```
class PickleDumpingThread(QThread):
   def __init__(self, data):
       super().__init__()
       self.data = data

   def run(self):
       pickle.dump(self.data["deque"], open(file, 'wb'))
       self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('threadFinished(int)'), self.currentThreadId())

class Analyzer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.dataDeque = deque(MAXLENGTH=10000)
        self.threadHandler = {}

    def onData(self, data):
        self.dataDeque.append({ "data": data, "createdTime": time.time() })
        self.cnt += 1
        if self.cnt % 10000 == 0:
            thread = PickleDumpingThread(self.dataDeque)
            self.connect(thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("threadFinished(int)"), self.threadFinished)
            thread.start() 
            self.threadHandler[thread.currentThreadId()] = thread

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def threadFinished(id):
        del self.threadHandler[id]
```

`self.threadHandler` is just to know how many threads are still running, you can get rid of it and `threadFinished` method

Comment: That's not thread-safe. The thread gets a reference to the deque, which will be modified whilst the pickling is taking place.

Comment: As @ekhumoro mentioned, it's not thread-safe, but in my case, it doesn't matter too much. 

This approach works, but its shortcoming is that it creates new thread every time data is saved. In my application, data is saved about 100 times, which means it creates more than 100 different threads. 
I solved this issue by using Worker. It only requires one thread, and it works. I'll post my solution in answer below.

Comment: @PYPL My new method using Worker still had delay in calling onData() function because of the running time of emit() method. I finally found a well working solution, by modifying really few things in your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not using `QThread` properly.

The result of printing

```
print("(Current Thread)", QThread.currentThread(),"\n")
print("(Current Thread)", int(QThread.currentThreadId()),"\n")
```

noticed me that the `PickleDumpingThread` I created was running in the main thread, not in some seperated thread.

The reason of this is `run()` is the only function in `QThread` that runs in seperate thread, so method like `savePickle` in `QThread` run in main thread.

---

**First Solution**

The proper usage of using signal was using Worker as following.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
class GenericThread(QThread):
    def run(self, *args):
       #  print("Current Thread: (GenericThread)", QThread.currentThread(),"\n")
        self.exec_()

class PickleDumpingWorker(QObject):
    pickleDumpingSignal = pyqtSignal(dict)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pickleDumpingSignal[dict].connect(self.savePickle)

    def savePickle(self, signal_dict)
        pickle.dump(signal_dict["deque"], open(file, "wb"))

pickleDumpingThread = GenericThread()
pickleDumpingThread.start()

pickleDumpingWorker = PickleDumpingWorker()
pickleDumpingWorker.moveToThread(pickleDumpingThread)

class Analyzer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.dataDeque = deque(MAXLENGTH=10000)
    def onData(self, data):
        self.dataDeque.append({
            "data": data, 
            "createdTime": time.time()
        })
        self.cnt += 1
        if self.cnt % 10000 == 0:
            pickleDumpingWorker.pickleDumpingSignal.emit({
                "action": savePickle,
                "deque": self.dataDeque
            })
            # pickle.dump(dataDeque, open(file, 'wb'))
```

This solution worked (pickle was dumped in seperate thread), but drawback of it is the data stream still delays about 0.5~1 seconds because of signal emit() function.

I found the best solution for my case is @PYPL 's code, but the code needs a few modifications to work.

---

**Final Solution**

Final solution is modifying @PYPL 's following code

```
thread = PickleDumpingThread(self.dataDeque)
thread.start()
```

to

```
self.thread = PickleDumpingThread(self.dataDeque)
self.thread.start()
```

The original code have some runtime error. It seems like thread is being garbage collected before it dumps the pickle because there's no reference to that thread after `onData()` function is finished.

Referencing the thread by adding `self.thread` solved this issue.

Also, it seems that the old `PickleDumpingThread` is being garbage collected after new `PickleDumpingThread` is being referenced by `self.thread` (because the old `PickleDumpingThread` loses its reference).

However, this claim is not verified (as I don't know how to view current active thread)..

Whatever, the problem is solved by this solution.

---

**EDIT**

My final solution have delay too. It takes some amount of time to call Thread.start()..

The real final solution I choosed is running infinite loop in thread and monitor some variables of that thread to determine when to save pickle. Just using infinite loop in thread takes a lots of cpu, so I added time.sleep(0.1) to decrease the cpu usage.

---

**FINAL EDIT**

OK..My 'real final solution' also had delay..
Even though I moved dumping job to another QThread, the main thread still have delay about pickle dumping time! That was weird.

But I found the reason. The reason was neither emit() performance nor whatever I thought.

The reason was, embarrassingly, [python's Global Interpreter Lock prevents two threads in the same process from running Python code at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/python-what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modul/18114882#18114882).

So probably I should use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) module in this case.

I'll post the result after modifying my code to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

**Edit after using `multiprocessing` module and future attempts**

**Using `multiprocessing` module**

Using `multiprocessing` module solved the issue of running python code concurrently, but the new essential problem arised. The new problem was 'passing shared memory variables between processes takes considerable amount of time' (in my case, passing `deque` object to child process took 1~2 seconds). I found that this problem cannot be removed as long as I use `multiprocessing` module. So I gave up to use `multiprocessing module

**Possible future attempts**

**1. Doing only File I/O in `QThread`**

The essential problem of pickle dumping is not writing to file, but serializing before writing to file. Python releases GIL when it writes to file, so disk I/O can be done concurrently in `QThread`. The problem is, serializing `deque` object to string before writing to file in `pickle.dump` method takes some amount of time, and during this moment, main thread is going to be blocked because of GIL.

Hence, following approach will effectively decrease the length of delay.

1. We somehow stringify the data object every time when `onData()` is called and push it to deque object
2. In `PickleDumpingThread`, just `join` the `list(deque)` object to stringify the `deque` object.
3. `file.write(stringified_deque_object)`. This can be done concurrently.

The step 1 takes really small time so it almost non-block the main thread.
The step 2 might take some time, but it obviously takes smaller time than serializing python object in `pickle.dump` method.
The step 3 doesn't block main thread.

**2. Using C extension**

We can manually release the GIL and reacquire the GIL in our custom C-extension module. But this might be dirty.

**3. Porting CPython to Jython or IronPython**

Jython and IronPython are other python implementations using Java and C#, respectively. Hence, they don't use GIL in their implementation, which means that `thread` really works like thread.
One problem is `PyQt` is not supported in these implementations..

**4. Porting to another language**

..

Note:

1. `json.dump` also took 1~2 seconds for my data.
2. Cython is not an option for this case. Although Cython has `with nogil:`, only non-python object can be accessed in that block (`deque` object cannot be accessed in that block) and we can't use `pickle.dump` method in that block.

Comment: Something else is going on... we have a PyQt5 app that outputs a huge file as a pickle, takes about 8 seconds for 200 megs, but the GUI does not block during this time... ie somehow the GIL is not interfering... maybe most of the time is spent writing to disk, what data structure are you pickling, can you describe it further?

Answer (score 0):

When the GIL is a problem the workaround is to subdivide the task into chunks in such a way that you can refresh the GUI between chunks.

E.g say you have one huge list of size S to dump, then you could try defining a class that derives from list and overrides getstate to return N subpickle objects, each one an instance of a class say Subpickle, containing S/N items of your list. Each subpickle exists only while pickling, and defines getstate to do 2 things:

- call qApp.processEvents() on gui, and
- return the sublist of S/N items.

While unpickling, each subpickle will refresh GUI and take the list of items; at end the total list is recreated in the original object from all the subpickles it will receive in its setstate.

You should abstract out the call to process events in case you want to unpickle the pickle in a console app (or non-pyqt gui). You would do this by defining a class-wide attribute on Subpickle, say process_events, to be None by default; if not None, the setstate calls it as a function. So by default there is no GUI refreshing between the subpickles, unless the app that unpikles sets this attribute to a callable before unpickling starts.

This strategy will give your GUi a chance to redraw during the unpickling process (and with only one thread, if you want).

Implementation depends on your exact data, but here is an example that demonstrates the principles for a large list:

```
import pickle

class SubList:
    on_pickling = None

    def __init__(self, sublist):
        print('SubList', sublist)
        self.data = sublist

    def __getstate__(self):
        if SubList.on_pickling is not None:
            print('SubList pickle state fetch: calling sub callback')
            SubList.on_pickling()
        return self.data

    def __setstate__(self, obj):
        if SubList.on_pickling is not None:
            print('SubList pickle state restore: calling sub callback')
            SubList.on_pickling()
        self.data = obj


class ListSubPickler:
    def __init__(self, data: list):
        self.data = data

    def __getstate__(self):
        print('creating SubLists for pickling long list')
        num_chunks = 10
        span = int(len(self.data) / num_chunks)
        SubLists = [SubList(self.data[i:(i + span)]) for i in range(0, len(self.data), span)]
        return SubLists

    def __setstate__(self, subpickles):
        self.data = []
        print('restoring Pickleable(list)')
        for subpickle in subpickles:
            self.data.extend(subpickle.data)
        print('final', self.data)

def refresh():
    # do something: refresh GUI (for example, qApp.processEvents() for Qt), show progress, etc
    print('refreshed')

data = list(range(100))  # your large data object
list_pickler = ListSubPickler(data)
SubList.on_pickling = refresh

print('\ndumping pickle of', list_pickler)
pickled = pickle.dumps(list_pickler)

print('\nloading from pickle')
new_list_pickler = pickle.loads(pickled)
assert new_list_pickler.data == data

print('\nloading from pickle, without on_pickling')
SubList.on_pickling = None
new_list_pickler = pickle.loads(pickled)
assert new_list_pickler.data == data
```

Easy to apply to dict, or even to make it adapt to the type of data it receives by using isinstance.